# Why is my levels function returning null for all of my variables?

Tags: r

Here is the code that I run beforehand.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(caret)

filename <- "iris.csv"

dataset <- read.csv(filename, header = FALSE)
  
colnames(dataset) <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species")


validation_index <- createDataPartition(dataset$Species, p=0.80sa, list=FALSE)
validation <- dataset[-validation_index,]
dataset <- dataset[validation_index,]
```

My question is why when I try to run `levels(dataset$Species)` all I get is `NULL` Species is a character variable and I should get 3 results: Iris-setosa, Iris-versicolor, and Iris-virginica. The code works when I import the dataset directly from R, but not when I try to import a csv file.

Comment: factors and characters look pretty similar in a dataframe but there are different. If `is.factor(dataset$Species)` gives you a FALSE, you may turn Species in a factor `dataset$Species <- as.factor(dataset$Species)` and then try `levels(dataset$Species)` again. Character variables do not have levels. If Species is a character the function `levels` won't find any levels and results in `NULL` .

Comment: You'll get your expected result if you just run `data(iris); levels(iris$Species)`.  The issue you're seeing is likely related to whatever is in `'iris.csv'`.

Answer (score 1):

tamtam's comment worked. I just added `dataset$Species <- as.factor(dataset$Species)` to my code after `colnames(dataset) <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species")`